# Tkinter: NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error, spyder

I have been following tutorials of how to create a graphical user interface (GUI), in order to get used to it because I will use it in the future. The majority of tutorials use these commands at the first lines:

```
from tkinter import *

root = tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("200x100")
root.mainloop()
```

If I run this simple code I get the following error:

File

> "C:/Users/Gerard/Dropbox/Master_Thesis_Gerard_Pujol/Python_Tryouts/creting_simpleGUI.py", line 11, in 
>       root=tk()
>
> NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

After that I changed my code, so I used something like that:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("200x100")
root.mainloop()
```

Now, the error is the following:

> "C:/Users/Gerard/Dropbox/Master_Thesis_Gerard_Pujol/Python_Tryouts/creting_simpleGUI.py", line 11, in 
>       root=tk()
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Do you know what's going wrong? Could you help me please?

I'm using Spyder for Python 3.3, but I suppose it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorials you've seen is probably for Python 2. In Python 3 they've changed the naming conventions. So instead of `root = tk()` in P2, it's `root = Tk()` in P3 (Tk() is a class, hence the capital T).

In your second example your should write `root = tk.Tk()` after the import statement

Comment: It runs! Thank you very much Olav, I was getting crazy!

Comment: It's `Tk` in python 2, also.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem which I found out was because my Python console window in Spyder was connected to a different .py file that I was working on earlier so I closed it and opened a new python console in Spyder and the problem was gone.